# C++ Simple compile error

Tags: c++, compilation, header

I am having a Compile issue.

- I have one Class
- I have one header file
- And of course Main to test my work.

But I am getting compile error, it is out of my understanding what I am doing wrong.

Header File:

```
#ifndef AGENT_H
#define AGENT_H

using namespace std;

class Agent
{
public:
    Agent(string);
    virtual ~Agent();
    private:
    string name;
};

#endif  /* AGENT_H */
```

Agent Class (Agent.cpp)

```
#include "Agent.h"

using namespace std;
Agent::Agent(string _name)
{
   this->name = _name;
}

Agent::~Agent()
{
    delete this->name;
}
```

And my Main:

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>

#include "Agent.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Agent agent1("Danila"); 
    return 0;
}
```

So I am getting such strange error:

```
undefined reference to `Agent::Agent(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `Agent::~Agent()'
/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `Agent::~Agent()'
```

Could you guys help me understand whats wrong there?

Comment: This isn't a compiler error. It's a **linker error**. Your final linker invocation must be missing one of the required object files.

Comment: That's not a compiler error, it's certainly not "strange", and this has nothing to do with C.

Comment: main does not have 17 lines. Can you recompile or show the real code you used?

Comment: Unrelated: since `name` was not allocated with `new`, you do not need to `delete` it.  `Agent`'s destructor should probably be empty.

Comment: you can't delete this->name. It is not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `#include <string>` in your header file.

Also, for good practice, keep the `using namespace`s in your .cpp files, if any.

Comment: or better yet, dont use `using namespace` at all.

Comment: Same error, it says undefined reference to `Agent::Agent(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' on line Agent agent1("Danila");

Comment: In that case it's probably because your Agent isn't being linked into the resulting executable (like one of the other answers says). It's also probably why it didn't catch the error in Agent. You'll have to look at the configuration options. Are Agent.h/cpp part of the same Netbeans project? Are they marked as being included in the build? Unfortunately, I haven't used Netbeans for C++, but I'm trying to apply what I know about Visual Studio here.

Answer (score 1):

You compiled without telling the compiler about `Agent.cpp`.  I.e. you need something like this, for g++:

```
$ g++ main.cpp Agent.cpp -o myprogram
```

Comment: I am using NetBeans, is it possible to do it there?

Comment: @WildGoat My guess--based on experience with other IDEs is that in order to compile smoothly, you have to add the file via an 'Add File' menu option or something like that.  Otherwise, the IDE doesn't know about `Agent.cpp` and doesn't put it in the Makefile it generates.  Alternately, there may be a project file which will be straightforward to edit--it will have a 'source' section.  As a last resort you should be able to manually edit the compiler command it generates directly, but I doubt this should be necessary.

Comment: I added it thought Netbeans as Add new Class, but as I can see in Makefile nothing changed, what should I add in makefile to make it working...

Comment: @WildGoat Add New Class sounds like exactly what you should be using.  Have you tried recompiling?  The Makefile probably won't be re-generated until then.  If the Makefile is auto-generated, don't edit it.

Comment: @WildGoat Hmmm, I'm just about out of tricks at this point--is there some command which remakes the Makefile, without compiling?  Like `qmake` if you've ever used Qt.